# change role samba 4 from BDC to PDC

Tags: samba4

Is it possible to change the role of a Samba4 BCD controller to PDC ?
PDC is broken and not accessible, I can't get any data from it.

PDC IP: 192.168.0.11
BDC IP: 192.168.0.4

Now my BDC syslog shows:

> samba[1376]:   Failed to connect host 192.168.0.11 (dd6537329-ca38-42e1-92e0-2f2d7db8ac3d._msdcs.test.local) on port 135 - NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE.

(which is normal because pdc is not working)

and something strange:

> samba[1704]:   /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: Failed to find object DC=test,DC=local for attribute fsmoRoleOwner - Cannot find attribute fsmoRoleOwner of DC=test,DC=local to calculate reference dn

I think changing role to PDC may resolve the problem.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: This article is useful to solve the problem:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Transferring_and_Seizing_FSMO_Roles

Answer (score 0):

It's strange becouse , the BDC it's just a backup of PDC in order to support the server fail and never have a locked situation like this moment.

May be your BDC didn't talk right with you PDC and it's not replicated (I hope not!!!) for this reason I don't think that elevating your BDC can fix the problem.
With extreme humility I'm not reccomended to work on samba to elevating on PDC exp if you  BDC it's your last resources.

So my suggestion is to build a real new windows active directory (not samba) from scratch on "on-the-fly machine" and try to link them togheter, importing all users and active directory settings.
It's more clean and safe.
Regards.